# How to check if filesystem is already mounted using C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, mount-point

Hi I am writing an application which mounts cgroup as shown below

```
mount("cgroup", "/sys/fs/cgroup", "tmpfs",0,NULL);
```

I am able to do this but I want to add a check to know if this is already mounted, how do I do that using C/C++? 
Is there any API or system API to get mount information.
I do not want to use system() call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to enumerate `/proc/mounts` using `getmntent_r`

Comment: Thank you so much @MSalters , this was helpful.